# How to do a if else in thymeleaf inside a loop that populate a table

Tags: html, spring-mvc, html-table, thymeleaf

I'm populating a table using a `<tr th:each>` and I want to put a if statement that evaluates the value if it is null, if the values is null I want to put this "--" instead of "null".

How can I do this using the `th:if` or other similar function I am new using thymeleaf?

This is my code:

```
<table id="datatable_fixed_column" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>lastname</th>
     <tr>
   <tbody>
      <tr th:each="nodeInfo : ${listOfData}">
        <td  th:if="${nodeInfo.name} == 'null'"> -- </td>
        <td  th:if="${nodeInfo.name} != 'null'" th:text="${nodeInfo.name}"></td>
```

EDITED: the code was edited and its working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your code to:

```
<tr th:each="nodeInfo : ${listOfData}">
   <td  th:if="${nodeInfo.name} == null">This is the value if the name is null</td>
   <td  th:if="${nodeInfo.name} != null">This is the value if the name is NOT null</td>
</tr>
```

Or even more consisely you could write:

```
<tr th:each="nodeInfo : ${listOfData}">
   <td  th:if="!${nodeInfo.name}">This is the value if the name is null</td>
   <td  th:if="${nodeInfo.name}">This is the value if the name is NOT null</td>
</tr>
```

which works because `${nodeInfo.name}` is evaluated to `true` when `name` is not null

You could also explore the use of `th:unless` instead of using `!=`

Check out [this](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/usingthymeleaf.html#simple-conditionals-if-and-unless) part of the documentation for more details.

Comment: thanks man i edited my code with your suggestion and it worked